# Gathering list of 2-d tensors from a 3-d tensor in Keras

Tags: machine-learning, tensorflow, nlp, keras

I have a 3-d Tensor named **main_decoder** of shape **(None,9,256)**

I want to extract 9 tensors of shape **(None,256)**

I have tried using Keras **gather** and the following is mode code snippet:

```
for i in range(0,9):
    sub_decoder_input = Lambda(lambda main_decoder:gather(main_decoder,(i)), name='lambda'+str(i))(main_decoder)
```

the resultant is 9 lambda layers of shape **(9,256)**

How can I modify it so that I can get or gather 9 tensors of shape **(None,256)**

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can slice the 3D tensor into 9 2D tensors and return a list of tensors from the `Lambda` layer.

```py
main_decoder = Input(shape=(9, 256))
sub_decoder_input = Lambda(lambda x: [x[:, i, :] for i in range(9)])(main_decoder)

print(sub_decoder_input)
[<tf.Tensor 'lambda_1/strided_slice:0' shape=(?, 256) dtype=float32>,
 <tf.Tensor 'lambda_1/strided_slice_1:0' shape=(?, 256) dtype=float32>,
 <tf.Tensor 'lambda_1/strided_slice_2:0' shape=(?, 256) dtype=float32>,
 <tf.Tensor 'lambda_1/strided_slice_3:0' shape=(?, 256) dtype=float32>,
 <tf.Tensor 'lambda_1/strided_slice_4:0' shape=(?, 256) dtype=float32>,
 <tf.Tensor 'lambda_1/strided_slice_5:0' shape=(?, 256) dtype=float32>,
 <tf.Tensor 'lambda_1/strided_slice_6:0' shape=(?, 256) dtype=float32>,
 <tf.Tensor 'lambda_1/strided_slice_7:0' shape=(?, 256) dtype=float32>,
 <tf.Tensor 'lambda_1/strided_slice_8:0' shape=(?, 256) dtype=float32>]
```